# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""?

Tags: android, numberformatexception

I keep on getting the error that my program stops every time i run. then, after reading a few forums, i think my problem lies with the conversion of integers and stuff. i tried to change from "parseInt" to "valueOf" but it rendered me no help. 
this is the main activity

```
package com.example.gutierrez.calculator;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView total;
EditText pewee_tray, pewee_price, sp_tray, sp_price, pullets_tray, pullets_price, small_price, small_tray, medium_price, medium_tray, large_price, large_tray, xlarge_tray, xlarge_price, jumbo_price, jumbo_tray;
 Button compute;

float tprice, pewprice, spprice, pulprice, smallprice, medprice, largeprice, xlprice, jumboprice;
int pewtray, sptray, pultray, smalltray, medtray, largetray, xltray, jumbotray;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);


    pewee_tray = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pewee_tray);
    pewee_price =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.pewee_price);

    sp_tray = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sp_tray);
    sp_price =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.sp_price);

   pullets_tray = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pullets_tray);
   pullets_price =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.pullets_price);

    small_tray = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.small_tray);
   small_price =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.small_price);

   medium_tray = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.medium_tray);
    medium_price =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.medium_price);

   large_tray = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.large_tray);
    large_price =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.large_price);

    xlarge_tray= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.xlarge_tray);
    xlarge_price =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.xlarge_price);

    jumbo_tray = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.jumbo_tray);
    jumbo_price =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.jumbo_price);

    pewtray = Integer.valueOf(pewee_tray.getText().toString());
    pewprice = Integer.valueOf(pewee_price.getText().toString());

    sptray = Integer.valueOf(sp_tray.getText().toString());
    spprice = Integer.valueOf(sp_price.getText().toString());

    pultray = Integer.valueOf(pullets_tray.getText().toString());
    pulprice = Integer.valueOf(pullets_price.getText().toString());

    smalltray = Integer.valueOf(pullets_tray.getText().toString());
    smallprice = Integer.valueOf(small_price.getText().toString());

    medtray = Integer.valueOf(pullets_tray.getText().toString());
    medprice = Integer.valueOf(medium_price.getText().toString());

    largetray = Integer.valueOf(large_tray.getText().toString());
    largeprice = Integer.valueOf(large_price.getText().toString());

    xltray = Integer.valueOf(large_tray.getText().toString());
    xlprice = Integer.valueOf(xlarge_price.getText().toString());

    jumbotray = Integer.valueOf(jumbo_tray.getText().toString());
    jumboprice = Integer.valueOf(jumbo_price.getText().toString());

    compute = (Button) findViewById(R.id.compute);

    compute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

                public void onClick(View v){
            tprice = pewprice * pewtray + spprice * sptray + pulprice * pultray + smallprice * smalltray + medprice * medtray + largeprice * largetray + xlprice * xltray + jumboprice * jumbotray;
            total.setText(String.valueOf(tprice));
        }
         });

}
}
```

and this one is the logcat entry:

```
09-18 16:55:15.347 2491-2491/com.example.gutierrez.calculator I/art: Not 
late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
09-18 16:55:15.347 2491-2491/com.example.gutierrez.calculator W/art: 
Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
09-18 16:55:15.577 2491-2491/com.example.gutierrez.calculator W/System: 
ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
/data/app/com.example.gutierrez.calculator-1/lib/x86
09-18 16:55:15.582 2491-2491/com.example.gutierrez.calculator I/InstantRun: 
starting instant run server: is main process
09-18 16:55:15.649 2491-2491/com.example.gutierrez.calculator W/art: Before 
Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter 

      android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)
      would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
    09-18 16:55:15.746 2491-2491/com.example.gutierrez.calculator D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    09-18 16:55:15.747 2491-2491/com.example.gutierrez.calculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.example.gutierrez.calculator, PID: 2491
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gutierrez.calculator/com.example.gutierrez.calculator.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
    Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:533)
       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
       at com.example.gutierrez.calculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:55)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) '
```

Comment: empty string is not an interger so.....

Comment: You should consider adding check if textview is empty(You get that when user does not enter a value) or using a try catch block with NumberFormatException. You have 2 options but checking for empty values is what you should do.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're trying to convert the value in the `EditText` even before the user has typed anything. Moves these lines in the `onClick` method :

```
pewtray = Integer.valueOf(pewee_tray.getText().toString());
pewprice = Integer.valueOf(pewee_price.getText().toString());

sptray = Integer.valueOf(sp_tray.getText().toString());
spprice = Integer.valueOf(sp_price.getText().toString());

pultray = Integer.valueOf(pullets_tray.getText().toString());
pulprice = Integer.valueOf(pullets_price.getText().toString());

smalltray = Integer.valueOf(pullets_tray.getText().toString());
smallprice = Integer.valueOf(small_price.getText().toString());

medtray = Integer.valueOf(pullets_tray.getText().toString());
medprice = Integer.valueOf(medium_price.getText().toString());

largetray = Integer.valueOf(large_tray.getText().toString());
largeprice = Integer.valueOf(large_price.getText().toString());

xltray = Integer.valueOf(large_tray.getText().toString());
xlprice = Integer.valueOf(xlarge_price.getText().toString());

jumbotray = Integer.valueOf(jumbo_tray.getText().toString());
jumboprice = Integer.valueOf(jumbo_price.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
 compute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

                    public void onClick(View v){

    pewtray = Integer.valueOf(pewee_tray.getText().toString());
    pewprice = Integer.valueOf(pewee_price.getText().toString());

    sptray = Integer.valueOf(sp_tray.getText().toString());
    spprice = Integer.valueOf(sp_price.getText().toString());

    pultray = Integer.valueOf(pullets_tray.getText().toString());
    pulprice = Integer.valueOf(pullets_price.getText().toString());

    smalltray = Integer.valueOf(pullets_tray.getText().toString());
    smallprice = Integer.valueOf(small_price.getText().toString());

    medtray = Integer.valueOf(pullets_tray.getText().toString());
    medprice = Integer.valueOf(medium_price.getText().toString());

    largetray = Integer.valueOf(large_tray.getText().toString());
    largeprice = Integer.valueOf(large_price.getText().toString());

    xltray = Integer.valueOf(large_tray.getText().toString());
    xlprice = Integer.valueOf(xlarge_price.getText().toString());

    jumbotray = Integer.valueOf(jumbo_tray.getText().toString());
    jumboprice = Integer.valueOf(jumbo_price.getText().toString());


                tprice = pewprice * pewtray + spprice * sptray + pulprice * pultray + smallprice * smalltray + medprice * medtray + largeprice * largetray + xlprice * xltray + jumboprice * jumbotray;
                total.setText(String.valueOf(tprice));
            }
             });
```

Use this "Check if a String contains numbers"

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9])");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("Here is ur string");

    if(m.find()){
        System.out.println("Hello "+m.find());
    }else
   {
 System.out.println("Please Enter Integer");
    }
```